# Obtener la cantidad de caracteres diferentes de un texto en C

Tags: c, comparaciones

Necesito hacer un programa en *C*, en el cual se ingresa una palabra y regresa la cantidad de caracteres diferentes de un texto `char[]`. Ejemplo: `"holahola"` solo se usaron 4 caracteres diferentes. Si hay por lo menos un espacio, debe tomarse en cuenta.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,b,a=0;
    char c[60];
    printf("Ingresa una cadena:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",&c);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("%s",c);
    a=0;
    b=strlen(c);
    for(i=0;i<=b;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<=b;j++){
            if(c[i]==c[j]){
                a++;
            }
        }
    }
    b=b-a;
    printf("Numero de simbolos: %d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` no es correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz un array de 256 números, inicializado en cero:

```
char ascii[256];
memset(ascii, 0, sizeof(ascii));
```

Procesa la cadena, incrementando el indice correspondiente al carácter:

```
int i;
char* cadena = "holahola"; /* tambien puedes obtenerla con scanf */
for( i=0 ; i < strlen(cadena); i++ ) {
    ascii[cadena[i]]++; /* segun el CHAR en i, incrementas */
}
```

Explicacion: `cadena[i]` obtiene el byte correspondiente a cada caracter (un numero entre 0 y 255) de `cadena`. Luego `ascii[cadena[i]]` accede al elemento en `ascii` que lleva la cuenta de cada caracter y el `++` incrementa dicho valor. Ej: el valor de `h` (que es 48) al final del ciclo es dos. `ascii['h'] == 2`.

Luego cuenta los no-cero y sabras el resultado:

```
int total=0;
for( i=0; i < 256 ; i++ ) {
  if (ascii[i] > 0) total++;
}
```

Ahora tienes el total. Tambien podrías calcular cual es la/las letra con mas repeticiones pues sabes cuantas ocurrencias hay de cada caracter.

Comment: muchas gracias !! solo me podrias decir como es que funciona esto: ascii[cadena[i]]++;

Comment: @CristianAlvarez en un momento edito la pregunta

Comment: @CristianAlvarez funciona incrementando el valor de el array ascii[]. cuando lee la letra h, cadena [i] toma el valor 104 (su equivalente ascii) luego se va al array ascii[104] que a su vez tiene un valor, que la pirmera vez es cero, pero al aplicar esa instrucción incrementa a 1 e incrementara un valor cada vez que lea una h; es equivalente a decir **ascii[cadena[i]] = ascii[cadena[i]] +1 **

Comment: Inicializando el array a cero: `char ascii[256] = {0};` evitas tener que llamar a `memset`.